# eclipse error not showing in file,How can i enable to show error?

Tags: eclipse

When i import a file from external, there is no error showing in eclipse like if the code has some reference class which i haven't imported yet

```
@Reference
  private transient NewsRoomService newsRoomService;
  @Reference
  private transient JSONConverter jsonConverter;

  @Reference
  private NewsAPI newsService;

  @Reference
  private CookieService cookieService;

  @Override
  protected void doGet(SlingHttpServletRequest request, SlingHttpServletResponse response)
      throws ServletException, IOException {
    try {
      response.setContentType(Constants.GENERIC_API_CONTENT_TYPE);
      response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);
      String userSession = cookieService.readCookieValue(request,Constants.USER_SESSION_COOKIE_NAME);
      boolean isNewsDetailsAPI = newsService.isNewsValid(Constants.GET_NEWS_DETAILS_API, userSession);
      if(isNewsDetailsAPI) {
      response.getWriter().write(jsonConverter
          .convertToJsonString(newsRoomService.getNewsRoomDetails(request, response)));
      }else {
          response.getWriter().write(Constants.SESSION_TIME_OUT);
          response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_FORBIDDEN);
      }
```

Here in above code NewsAPI is seperate class which i haven't imported yet but in eclipse not showing error on that clsss teeling class not found 
Have tried this but error is showing in console. I want the red error to be shown under my file itself

Comment: I am not sure if I understood it correctly but if you have just opened a file from eclipse it will not show any indications of errors or warnings. You have to include that file in your project to see the missing links and errors. Its just showing you a file as text editor will show

Comment: The file must be contained in a source folder of a Java project so that it can be compiled and problems can be displayed. You can recognize it by the editor icon: an outline `J` instead of a regular `J` means that it is not a compilable Java file of a source folder.